# Document mode deprecated in IE 11 and checklist?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Microsoft site specified that document modes will be deprecated. I would like to know the checklist that required to migrate legacy pages to IE-Edge compatible.
Any kind help is appreciated.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What checklist? Microsoft doesn't mention one. It does offer some guidelines in the document you link to... if that counts.

Comment: I found cookbook but the information specified in that document is quite diverse and I would like to know migration experiences from the senior developers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/dn384059%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the variety of code patterns folks have used over the years and the amount of creativity that's been levelled at various problems, you're not going to find such a list.  (Believe me, had there been such a list, it would have been included in the Cookbook.)

The closest, most practical tools that I know of are:

- The [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) (when coupled with [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/)).
- The [compatibility scanner](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/compat-scan) provided by [modern.ie](https://www.modern.ie/en-us).
- The developer tools built into the latest versions of popular browsers.
- Your preferred search engine, along with your own trial and error.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Thank you very much Lance. I will look them up.